# Get service from non-registered class

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I have this in my program:

```
    var options = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<RazorPagesMovieContext>>();
```

But i didn't add (register) `DbContextOptions` anywhere in the project.
The `GetRequiredService` returns a valid object of the mentioned class.
Hows it possible?
The only place i registered some things via `ServiceProvider` is the following:

```
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    services.AddDbContext<RazorPagesMovieContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("RazorPagesMovieContext")));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AddDbContext<TDbContext>()` method also registers a `DbContextOptions<TDbContext>`.

See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/c2a39d700963f71c0035fa297aae6ec430578951/src/EFCore/Extensions/EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L502.

Comment: Is the reason that it registers dbcontextoptions too, because its the dependency of tdbcontext?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the why.